# SQL Server : case when Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have two tables `Students` and `Grades`.

- `Students` contain three columns `ID`, `Name`, and `Marks`.

Grades

[image: Grade table]

Students

[image: Student table]

I am applying a case when statement to get a `max_marks` column in the student table as well for that I have written this code but it's not working.

Code:

```
SELECT
    Name,
    CASE 
        WHEN marks < 10 THEN 9
        WHEN marks < 20 THEN 19
        WHEN marks < 30 THEN 29
        WHEN marks < 40 THEN 39
        WHEN marks < 50 THEN 49
        WHEN marks < 60 THEN 59
        WHEN marks < 70 THEN 69
        WHEN marks < 80 THEN 79
        WHEN marks < 90 THEN 89
        ELSE 99 
    END AS max_mark
```

Comment: Looks like you have switched table data above.

Comment: "but it's not working" is not a helpful problem description, especially when the posted code is only a segment. Also, it's a case *expression*, not a statement

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 1):

```
select s.id,s.name,s.marks,m.grade
from students as s
join marks as m on s.marks between m.min_mark and m.max_mark
```